# Buttons on TouchImageView?

Tags: java, android, touchimageview

I'm using this awesome class to implement zoom in my imageView:

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

TouchImageView extends ImageView (so has the same properties) and adds zooming features. 
But I have a problem: I have small buttons on the imageview, and I set them in particular points of the image.. and if I zoom the image, the buttons don't remain in the correct point, they aren't zoomed with the image!

Can you help me?

Comment: use proportionate values and matrix to set on imageview.